# How to generate a PGP Certificate in Java

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, pgp, openpgp

I am currently using Bouncy Castle library (1.45) for the generation of X509 Certificate (i.e. X509V1CertificateGenerator), and now I need to be able to create and import/export a PGP Certificate into/from the keystore. However, I am not seeing any support for the generation of a PGP Certificate in their "openpgp" package.

All I am seeing is PGPKeyRingGenerator, PGPSignatureGenerator. I am open to using another Java library. Thank you very much.

Comment: PGP keys are not called "certificates", hence the problem. Most likely what you need is PGPKeyRingGenerator.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to be able to generate a PGP Certificate which I can import into the keystore. I can generate public/private PGP keys using PGPKeyRingGenerator, but how can I embed the public key in an actual PGP Certificate?

Comment: Did you read my answer? There exist NO "PGP certificates". PGP doesn't have a concept of "certificates". Read the RFC 4880 on OpenPGP format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bouncy Castle can do that, you're just mixing up certificates vs. keys, as Eugene suggested.

It's X509 Certificate, and an OpenPGP keypair. Certificates are stored in a certificate store, and OpenPGP keys are stored in a keyring.

If you want to create such a PGP Keypair, see [BouncyCastle Example of generating an OpenPGP Keypair](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcpg-jdk15/1.45/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/RSAKeyPairGenerator.java).

If you want to import the OpenPGP keypair you generated, you need to deal with a *public* keyring and a *secret* keyring (optional, if you have the private part of the key).

To import a foreign key, use [PGPPublicKeyRing.insertPublicKey](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPPublicKeyRing.html). 
To import a private key, use [PGPSecretKeyRing.insertSecretKey](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPSecretKeyRing.html).

Those methods are static, be sure to generate a keyring beforhand (i.e. a certificate-store alike). Furthermore you should read about PGP's or gnupgs basic concecpt, before using these classes.